# Why am i getting a Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'nextShape' when it is right above the function

Tags: swift, xcode

**I'm getting an error "Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'nextShape'" at the line self.nextShape() I don't understand why. Can anybody help**

```
func nextShape() {
    let newShapes  = swiftris.newShape()
    guard let fallingShape = newShapes.fallingShape else {
        return
    }
    self.scene.addPreviewShapeToScene(shape: newShapes.nextShape!) {}
    self.scene.movePreviewShape(shape: fallingShape){
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.scene.startTicking()
    }
}
func gameDidBegin(swiftris: Swiftris) {
    levelLabel.text = "\(swiftris.level)"
    scorelabel.text = "\(swiftris.score)"
    scene.tickLengthMillis = TickLengthLevelOne

    // The following is false when restarting a new game
    if swiftris.nextShape != nil && swiftris.nextShape!.blocks[0].sprite == nil {
        scene.addPreviewShapeToScene(shape:swiftris.nextShape!) {
            self.nextShape()
        }
    } else {
        nextShape()
    }

}
```

Comment: You have not posted any code with the line `self.nextShape()`.

Comment: Please add whole function gameDidBegin()